# Changing the content-type using Nokogiri doesn't work

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I want to change the charset in the "http-equiv" content-type tag. Because I'm working with Nokogiri in other parts of my code I'd like to use it for this processing step too.

This is example code:

```
http_equiv = doc.at('meta[@http-equiv]')
    if !http_equiv.nil? && !http_equiv["http-equiv"].nil? && http_equiv["http-equiv"].downcase.eql?("content-type")
        http_equiv["content"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    end
content = doc.to_html.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

The problem is that the input content is alway the same as the output content. Nokogiri didn't do anything.

Based on an answer I created a real world example which won't work in contrast to the generated example.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/hooligans-gegen-salafisten-demo-in-koeln-eskaliert-a-999401.html"))

content_type = doc.at('meta[@http-equiv="Content-Type"]')
content_type['content'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'

puts doc.to_html
```

Comment: Give us a minimal example of the HTML you're parsing.

Comment: `doc = require 'open-air'`? What is that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
  </head>
  <body>
  foo
  </body>
</html>
EOT

content_type = doc.at('meta[@http-equiv="content-type"]')
content_type['content'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
puts doc.to_html
```

Running that outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
  </head>
  <body>
  foo
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also do

```
content_type['content'] << '; charset=UTF-8'
```

if you're only appending to the existing value.

---

> It doesn't change the content-type.

It changes the content type in the tag, however there is more to it since it seems you don't want to change the content-type marker, you want to change the encoding of the document itself at output. Once you do that, Nokogiri will also change the meta tag to match:

```
doc.to_html(encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

will tell Nokogiri to output the HTML, trying to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. There is no guarantee that will occur correctly though, because there are some incompatibilities.

Your original attempt using:

```
content = doc.to_html.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

won't work correctly, because of HTML encoding that occurs on special characters. You have to change the character encoding before they are HTML-encoded, which should happen if you use `to_html(encoding: 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: Have a look at my question - I took your answer and used it with a real world website. It doesn't change the content-type.

Comment: It does change the content type. It doesn't change the document's encoding, which is a different question. If you want that to happen see the added answer.